# Boto3 upload_file is silently failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a file in s3 bucket and the following code i have used to achieve the same.

**Code**

```
accessKey = ''

secretKey = ''

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id = accessKey, aws_secret_access_key = secretKey,)

s3 = session.resource('s3')

try:

   response =s3.Object(bucket_name,'sample.docx').upload_file(Filename='C:/Users/Anushka/Desktop/sample.docx')

except Exception as e:

   return e
```

The code does not do anything not even raising any error and if I print "response", "None" gets printed on the shell. I am not able to understand what is the problem with the code.

Comment: This does not seem to be valid python `\=`?

Comment: **Side-note:** It is not good practice to store credentials in your code. Instead, if this is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, assign an IAM Role to the instance. If it is running on your own computer, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store credentials in the ~/.aws/credentials` file. In both cases, boto3 will automatically find and use the credentials.

Comment: Uploading a file does not provide a return code. You appear to be missing a closing quote after `'C:/Users/Anushka/Desktop/sample.docx`, which is why the remaining code is shown in red. Is this your _actual_ code?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: To debug this remove try/except block and execute this in the plain python shell (or IPython)